# Is it ok to use class as an API parameter?

Tags: oop

I have these methods

```
public class ReportService
{
    public DataTable GetCustomerReportDataTable(String dateFrom, String dateTo, String cif, String customerName, String region, String branch, String salesCode);
    public DataTable GetProductReportDataTable(String dateFrom, String dateTo, String cif, String customerName, String product, String region, String branch, String salesCode);
}
```

And want to refactor it to (below) based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079514/convince-my-coworker-that-methods-with-26-parameters-are-bad-practice) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804691/what-is-the-standard-number-of-parameters-that-a-java-method-should-have/)

```
public class CustomerReportFilter
{

    public String DateFrom { get; set; }
    public String DateTo { get; set; }
    public String CIF { get; set; }
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public String Region { get; set; }
    public String Branch { get; set; }
    public String SalesCode { get; set; }
}

public class ProductReportFilter
{

    public String DateFrom { get; set; }
    public String DateTo { get; set; }
    public String CIF { get; set; }
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public String Product { get; set; }
    public String Region { get; set; }
    public String Branch { get; set; }
    public String SalesCode { get; set; }
}

public class ReportService
{
    public DataTable GetCustomerReportDataTable(CustomerReportFilter filter);
    public DataTable GetProductReportDataTable(ProductReportFilter filter);
}
```

**Question:**

What if the API caller is from other language/technology?
They'd be tied to `CustomerReportFilter` and `ProductReportFilter` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I implement this API with ASP.Net MVC, it's JSON Binding will automatically convert JSON string into strongly-typed .Net object. So different language can call this API using their REST client then POST a JSON string.

For other language like Java, I've read [RESTful Java client with java.net.URL](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/) .

I assume being tied to API parameter class is no problem because of the auto-converter.

UPDATE:
[Here](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html), it's clearly stated that `The solution is to create a Data Transfer Object that can hold all the data for the call. It needs to be serializable to go across the connection.`
So, it's recommended to use class as the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are asking but for your function the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern is suitable.

```
Report.Builder builder = new Report.Builder();
builder.setDateFrom(...).setDateTo(...).setCif(...);
DataTable tbl = builder.build();
```

This way you never confuse your strings order and can omit any optional strings.

Comment: If I create builder, it's basically the same if I change parameter to property. That means it's optional, is it not? If I want to make all parameter to mandatory. Is builder pattern without IsNullOrEmpty checking suitable?

Comment: In the build() function of the builder you can check for the validity of the parameters. Even if all parameters are mandatory, using Builder makes sense, because it's easy to accidentally misplace parameters in such a long list of Strings whereas Builder gives an easier semantics.