# Is it good that we have a method with more parameter?

Tags: java

is it good work that design a method that have more parameter(for example five parameter) in java?

```
 public List<Node> loadByParentAndNeighbor(Map<String, Object> properties, String parentLabel, String neighborLabel, String parentRelation, String neighborRelation) {
     return null;
 }
```

Comment: It depends on what the method is doing. Why would it be bad?

Comment: Why would you want to create a method that takes 5 parameters and returns `null` ? :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [When a method has too many parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244860/when-a-method-has-too-many-parameters)

Comment: mr alfasin , it is an example that I write here.

Answer (score 1):

**case -1** : If the parameters are *unrelated* , then they cannot be put into a single container (like a list) and passed to this method. So it would be *acceptable* to have a method with several parameters.

**case-2** : If the parameters are *related*.For example if an Object has 10 fields, and 5 of them are being passed to a method, then it would be *cleaner* and more *readable* to pass the object itself (rather than 5 of its parameters.)

Comment: in this method that I post it , parentLabel and parentRelation is related , neighborLabel and neighborRelation is related.
can I put them in map and method would be have three map parameter.
is it good???

Comment: @user3807246 - This is more of a design issue. You should *not* pass more than what the method needs (technically..) unless it simplifies *something* significantly. How are the fields related?

Answer (score 0):

Too many parameters is considered bad practice and should be avoided where possible.

The reason is that if you have the following function:

```
public void addUser(String username, String firstname, String lastname)
```

It is very easy to confuse the parameters when calling the functions (was the first parameter firstname or username?).

```
addUser("johnd", "John", "Doe");
```

To solve this, it is always best to group parameters when you get too many. For instance into a class called `Name` with a member `firstname` and `lastname`.

```
Name name = new Name("John", "Doe");
addUser("johnd", name);
```

This problem also arises with fewer parameters (as in my example) but with more, especially when there are many of the same type, it gets gradually worse.