# Method edit in class data access cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, jsp

I'm running a jsp for the edit function and for some reason, the String idTemp used to parse the int id kept on getting recognized as some data for the update to be executed.

```js
<%@page import="dao.DataAccess"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String idTemp = request.getParameter("id"); //1
            int id = Integer.parseInt(idTemp); //2            
            String station = request.getParameter("station"); //3
            String date = request.getParameter("date"); //4
            String shift = request.getParameter("shift"); //5
            String uprice = request.getParameter("uprice"); //6
            String cashliters = request.getParameter("cashliters"); //7
            String cashamt = request.getParameter("cashamt"); //8
            String cardliters = request.getParameter("cardliters"); //9
            String cardamt = request.getParameter("cardamt"); //10
            String chargeliters = request.getParameter("chargeliters"); //11
            String chargeamt = request.getParameter("chargeamt"); //12 
            String gcliters = request.getParameter("gcliters"); //13
            String gcamt = request.getParameter("gcamt"); //14
            String fleetliters = request.getParameter("fleetliters"); //15
            String fleetamt = request.getParameter("fleetamt"); //16
            String tappingliters = request.getParameter("tappingliters"); //17
            String tappingamt = request.getParameter("tappingamt"); //18
            String hosefillliters = request.getParameter("hosefillliters"); //19
            String hosefillamt = request.getParameter("hosefillamt"); //20
            String calibrateliters = request.getParameter("calibrateliters"); //21
            String calibrateamt = request.getParameter("calibrateamt"); //22
            String grossliters = request.getParameter("grossliters"); //23
            String grossamt = request.getParameter("grossamt"); //24
            String cashdepoamt = request.getParameter("cashdepoamt"); //25            
            String checkdepoamt = request.getParameter("checkdepoamt"); //26
            String variance = request.getParameter("variance"); //27
            String cashier = request.getParameter("cashier"); //28
            String nooftrans = request.getParameter("nooftrans"); //29
            String tank1level = request.getParameter("tank1level"); //30
            String tank1liters = request.getParameter("tank1liters"); //31
            String tank2level = request.getParameter("tank2level"); //32
            String createdate = request.getParameter("createdate"); //33
            String userid = request.getParameter("userid"); //34
            String transmit = request.getParameter("transmit"); //35
            String transmitdate = request.getParameter("transmitdate"); //36
            String tank2liters = request.getParameter("tank2liters"); //37
            String product = request.getParameter("product"); //38
            
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            da.edit(id, station, date, shift, uprice, cashliters, cashamt, cardliters, cardamt, chargeliters, chargeamt, gcliters, gcamt, fleetliters, fleetamt, tappingliters, tappingamt, hosefillliters, hosefillamt, calibrateliters, calibrateamt, grossliters, grossamt, cashdepoamt, checkdepoamt, variance, cashier, nooftrans, tank1level, tank1liters, tank2level, createdate, userid, transmit, transmitdate, tank2liters, product);
            
            response.sendRedirect("/CRUD_News/AllPost");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

error is on line:

```js
            da.edit(id, station, date, shift, uprice, cashliters, cashamt, cardliters, cardamt, chargeliters, chargeamt, gcliters, gcamt, fleetliters, fleetamt, tappingliters, tappingamt, hosefillliters, hosefillamt, calibrateliters, calibrateamt, grossliters, grossamt, cashdepoamt, checkdepoamt, variance, cashier, nooftrans, tank1level, tank1liters, tank2level, createdate, userid, transmit, transmitdate, tank2liters, product);
```

The error is:

```js
method edit in class data access cannot be applied to given types
required: int, +37 String
found: int, +36 String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

What do you suggest I do to keep the idTemp string yet be able to execute without having it in the data to be inserted?

**Edit: EditPost.java**

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package servlet;

import dao.DataAccess;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Thang
 */
public class EditPost extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             {
        String idTemp = request.getParameter("id");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idTemp);
        request.setAttribute("getNewsById", DataAccess.getNewById(id));
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("EditPost.jsp");
        try {
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EditPost.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

**DataAccess.java**

```js
    public void edit(int id, String station, String description, String date, String shift, String uprice, String cashliters, String cashamt, String cardliters, String cardamt, String chargeliters, String chargeamt, String gcliters, String gcamt, String fleetliters, String fleetamt, String tappingliters, String tappingamt, String hosefillliters, String hosefillamt, String calibrateliters, String calibrateamt, String grossliters, String grossamt, String cashdepoamt, String checkdepoamt, String variance, String cashier, String nooftrans, String tank1level, String tank1liters, String tank2level, String createdate, String userid, String transmit, String transmitdate, String tank2liters, String product){
        try {
            String sql = "update DailySales SET dsStnCode = ?, dsDate = ?, dsShift = ?, dsUPrice = ?, dsCashLiters = ?, dsCashAmt = ?, dsCardLiters = ?, dsCardAmt = ?, dsChargeLiters = ?, dsChargeAmt = ?, dsGCLiters = ?, dsGCAmt = ?, dsFleetLiters = ?, dsFleetAmt = ?, dsTappingLiters = ?, dsTappingAmt = ?, dsHosefillLiters = ?, dsHoseFillAmt = ?, dsCalibrateLiters = ?, dsCalibrateAmt = ?, dsGrossLiters = ?, dsGrossAmt = ?, dsCashDepoAmt = ?, dsCheckDepoAmt = ?, dsVariance = ?, dsCashier = ?, dsNoOfTrans = ?, dsTank1Level = ?, dsTank1Liters = ?, dsTank2Level = ?, dsCreateDate = ?, dsUserID = ?, dsTransmit = ?, dsTransmitDate = ?, dsTank2Liters = ?, dsProduct = ?" + " where id = ?";

            PreparedStatement ps= DBUtils.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, station);
            ps.setString(2, date);
            ps.setString(3, shift);
            ps.setString(4, uprice);
            ps.setString(5, cashliters);
            ps.setString(6, cashamt);
            ps.setString(7, cardliters);            
            ps.setString(8, cardamt);
            ps.setString(9, chargeliters);
            ps.setString(10, chargeamt);
            ps.setString(11, gcliters);
            ps.setString(12, gcamt);
            ps.setString(13, fleetliters);
            ps.setString(14, fleetamt);
            ps.setString(15, tappingliters);
            ps.setString(16, tappingamt);
            ps.setString(17, hosefillliters);
            ps.setString(18, hosefillamt);
            ps.setString(19, calibrateliters);
            ps.setString(20, calibrateamt);
            ps.setString(21, grossliters);
            ps.setString(22, grossamt);
            ps.setString(23, cashdepoamt);
            ps.setString(24, checkdepoamt);
            ps.setString(25, variance);
            ps.setString(26, cashier);
            ps.setString(27, nooftrans);
            ps.setString(28, tank1level);
            ps.setString(29, tank1liters);
            ps.setString(30, tank2level);
            ps.setString(31, createdate);
            ps.setString(32, userid);
            ps.setString(33, transmit);
            ps.setString(34, transmitdate);
            ps.setString(35, tank2liters);
            ps.setString(36, product);             
            ps.setInt(37, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }
```

**EditPost.jsp**

```html
<%-- 
    Document   : EditPost
    Created on : Aug 8, 2015, 11:08:34 PM
    Author     : Thang
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Edit</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Edit News</h1>
        <div style="width: 900px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
            <c:forEach items="${getNewsById}" var="p">
            <form action="JSP/ManagerEditPost.jsp" method="post">                
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${p.id}">
                Station:
                <input type="text" name="station" value="${p.station}" style="width: 200px" value="South Area Auto Gas Corp. - Kawit" readonly><br><br>
                <!--Title:<br>
                <input type="text" name="title" style="width: 200px" ><br>
                -->
                Date:
                <input type="date" value="${p.date}" name="date" style="width: 200px"><br><br>
                <!--Description:<br>
                <input type="text" name="description" style="width: 200px"><br>
                -->
                Shift: 
                <select name="shift">
                    <option value="${p.shift}">${p.shift}</option>
                    <option value="GY">GY</option>
                    <option value="AM">AM</option>
                    <option value="PM">PM</option>
                </select><br><br>                  
                Product: 
                <select name="product">
                    <option value="${p.product}">${p.product}</option>                    
                    <option value="LPG">LPG</option>
                    <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
                    <option value="Unleaded">Unleaded</option>
                    <option value="Premium">Premium</option>                    
                </select><br><br>
                U/Price:
                <input type="text" value="${p.uprice}" name="uprice" style="width: 200px">
                No. of Transaction:
                <input type="text" value="${p.nooftrans}" name="nooftrans" style="width: 50px"><br><br>
                Cashier:
                <input type="text" value="${p.cashier}" name="cashier" style="width: 300px"><br><br>
                Tank 1:
                <input type="text" value="${p.tank1level}" name="tank1level" placeholder="gauge" style="width: 50px">
                <input type="text" value="${p.tank1liters}" name="tank1liters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br><br>
                Tank 2:
                <input type="text" value="${p.tank2level}" name="tank2level" placeholder="gauge" style="width: 50px">
                <input type="text" value="${p.tank2liters}" name="tank2liters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br><br><br><br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Liters</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cash:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.cashliters}" name="cashliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.cashamt}" name="cashamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Card:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.cardliters}" name="cardliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="${p.cardamt}" name="cardamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Charge:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.chargeliters}" name="chargeliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="${p.chargeamt}" name="chargeamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>G.C:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.gcliters}" name="gcliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.gcamt}" name="gcamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fleet Card:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.fleetliters}" name="fleetliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.fleetamt}" name="fleetamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tapping:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.tappingliters}" name="tappingliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.tappingamt}" name="tappingamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hosefill:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.hosefillliters}" name="hosefillliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.hosefillamt}" name="hosefillamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Calibration: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.calibrateliters}" name="calibrateliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.calibrateamt}" name="calibrateamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gross: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.grossliters}" name="grossliters" placeholder="liters" style="width: 50px"><br></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="${p.grossamt}" name="grossamt" placeholder="amount" style="width: 100px"><br></td>
                    </tr>                     
                </table>
                
                <br><br>
                Deposit Amount:<br>
                <input type="text" value="${p.cashdepoamt}" name="cashdepoamt" placeholder="gauge" style="width: 100px">
                <input type="text" value="${p.checkdepoamt}" name="checkdepoamt" placeholder="liters" style="width: 100px">
                <input type="text" value="${p.variance}" name="variance" placeholder="liters" style="width: 100px"><br><br>

                <!--
                START NOTE: ADD TO EDIT LATER
                -->
                User ID:
                <input type="text" value="${p.userid}" name="userid" style="width: 300px"><br><br>
                Transmit
                <input type="text" value="${p.transmit}" name="transmit" style="width: 300px"><br><br>
                Transmit Date:
                <input type="date" value="${p.transmitdate}" name="transmitdate" style="width: 300px"><br><br>
                Create Date:
                <input type="date" value="${p.createdate}" name="createdate" style="width: 300px"><br><br>

                
                <!--
                NOTE: ADD TO EDIT LATER
                -->
                
                <!--Detail:<br>
                <textarea name="detail" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></textarea><br>
                -->
                <!--
                Category: 
                <select name="category">
                    <option value="World">World</option>
                    <option value="Tech">Tech</option>
                    <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
                </select><br>
                -->
                <!--Image:<br>
                <input type="text" name="image" style="width: 200px"><br>
                -->
                <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            </c:forEach>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Avoid using java code in jsp page and show the edit method

Comment: @SpringLearner - do you mean the edit.java file? I'm sorry I'm a beginner at this so I'm not familiar with the terms yet. I edited the post.

Comment: show your edit method and check no of values passing with no of columns.there is miss match

Comment: Please post the code for the `DataAccess` class' `edit` method.  You have miscounted the number of arguments in your code comments above.  the variable `idTemp` is never passed to `edit` so you cannot count it as one of the 38 arguments.

Comment: added the dataaccess.java's edit method

Comment: arguments miss match. You are passing 37 parameters to edit method in jsp,but in your Java class taking 38 parameters and your edit query also have 37 parameters,check with arguments miss match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all avoid the method with so many parameters. [Some
   reasons here for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244860/when-a-method-has-too-many-parameters)
2. dont write java code in JSP
3. You are missing `String description` parameter.

The number of parameters are different.
Required number of parameters for DataAccess classes edit method are **37**.
You are passing **36**. You need to call the method according to its signature ie according to number and type of parameter.

> The name of the parameter you are missing is `String description` .

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you that the `edit` method in `DataAccess.java` requires you to pass in one int followed by **37** Strings. But when you call `da.edit(...)` in your jsp file you are passing in one int followed by **36** Strings.

Make sure what you are passing to `edit()` matches the method definition. I believe you are missing the third parameter: `String description`

Comment: thanks so much and i'm sorry for my carelessness :) it worked.