# Using the $injector instance directly vs. obtaining dependencies as parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within Angular, is it considered a good practice getting the dependencies directly from an $injector instance, rather than as parameters?

I have the problem that my controllers started having a lot of dependencies, so rather than:

```
myApp.controller(['$scope', 'Dep1', 'Dep2', 'Dep3', function($scope, Dep1, Dep2, Dep3) {
    ...
}]);
```

I would do:

```
myApp.controller(['$scope', '$injector', function($scope, $injector) {
    var Dep1 = $injector.get('Dep1');
    var Dep2 = $injector.get('Dep2');
    var Dep3 = $injector.get('Dep3');
}]);
```

I find it the same functionality-wise, but with much less clutter on the parameters. I suppose that this will make my components slightly less easy to test though, right?

What do you think?

Comment: If you always have to use Dep1,Dep2,Dep3 in multiple controllers. You could create a service that exports those as properties, and then just depend upon that 1 service.

Comment: Testing is a factor.  The real issue is that a large number of dependencies often indicates that your controllers are doing too much.  What constitutes "large" depends on the individual case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my opinion and after reading the following posts:

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122466/what-is-the-difference-between-using-the-service-locator-anti-pattern-and-using)

[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382109/how-to-avoid-a-large-number-of-dependencies-in-angularjs)

[Angular's documentation on DI (Dependency Injection)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Your second approach in order to minimize the long dependency list is considered as **Service Locator Anti Pattern**.
See - [Service locator AntiPattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-anti-pattern)

**Using the Service Locator Anti Pattern is bad because** it will make your life as a maintenance developer worse because you will need to use considerable amounts of brain power to grasp the implications of every change you make. Using the $injector obfuscates the actual dependencies of the resource (in this case controller) and kills maintainability.

In addition, according to [angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) the the preferable way is:

> Using the inline array annotation (preferred)

If your controller is ending up using so many dependencies maybe you are doing something wrong, Maybe you broke the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). consider:

1. Delegate more of the logic to service(s) that are injected in
2. Separate out into different controllers, so each only has (just about) 1 responsibility

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you write the code and how is easy to you and make you flexible to write code. I always write the controllers in this way hope it will help :}

```
var appCtrl = function($scope, others){...}
app.controller('appCtrl',['$scope', 'others', appCtrl]);
```